# Drop files on Tauri icon in Dock

Tags: tauri

Is there any way to create a Tauri application for macOS that will accept files and folders dropped onto the Tauri icon in the Dock?

In Electron, I think it is possible by defining `CFBundleTypeExtensions` in the electron-builder configuration file and enumerating the file extensions.

How do you do that in Tauri?
I couldn't find any documentation.

Comment: Currently with Tauri this seems to be impossible ... there's an open issue for MacOS file associations here https://github.com/tauri-apps/tauri/issues/3736

Comment: Thanks for letting me know.
The app I want to make now is important to drop and open, so I will give up on Tauri for now and proceed with Electron development.
Thanks to you, I was able to make my decision. Thank you!